# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta con LIKE y si no se cumple que salte al siguiente LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy algo liado con las consultas SQL hace bastante no hago una de esta índole. Tengo que hacer un `SELECT` de varios campos y si no se cumple que salte a otro. Un ejemplo de ello seria:

```
SELECT * from cli_propiedades 
WHERE status<66 AND estado=1 
AND codigo_propiedad like '<variable>%' 
OR localidad like '%<variable>%' OR direccion like'%<variable>%' 
OR cp like '%<variable>%' order by id;
```

lo que necesito es que si por ejemplo `codigo_propiedad` no se cumple o es `NULL` que salte al otro `LIKE` y asi sucesivamente, ¿Algún consejo?.

Comment: Cuál es el problema que estás teniendo? Podrías agregar datos de la tabla, el resultado esperado, y el resultado que estás obteniendo? Lo que contestó @Roy es correcto, con eso debería funcionar tu consulta.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras si funciona, pero lo que quiero es ver si por ejemplo si  `codigo_propiedad` no tiene esa variable, quiero que salte al otro  `LIKE`, y asi sucesivamente y si coincide en varios registros  `localidad` o  `direccion`, tambien que los muestre simplemente eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poné las condiciones entre paréntesis:

```
SELECT * from cli_propiedades 
WHERE status<66 AND estado=1 
AND (codigo_propiedad like '<variable>%' 
OR localidad like '%<variable>%' OR direccion like'%<variable>%' 
OR cp like '%<variable>%') order by id;
```

También puedes agregar condiciones multiples:

```
(
   (codigo_propiedad like '<variable>%' AND direccion = 'LO-QUE-QUIERAS')
   OR localidad like '%<variable>%' OR direccion like'%<variable>%' 
   OR cp like '%<variable>%'
)
```

[Ejemplos](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php)

Comment: Con parentesis o sin el me da el mismo resultado, aun así Gracias :)

Comment: @juank podrías ejemplificar lo que necesitas? o en todo caso las condiciones lógicas para que te demos una mano?

Comment: Quiero que si  `codigo_propiedad` no tiene esa variable que salte al otro `LIKE` y asi sucesivamente y a suvez que si en ejemplo `localidad` y/o `direccion` conitene esa variable que muestre la info (no sé si me doy a entender)

Answer (score 6):

Según te entiendo, lo que buscas es que si no se cumple una condición se pase a la siguiente, lo que por otro lado sería decir, que "corte" el filtro con la primer condición verificada. Para hacer esto, creo que la forma más sencilla es usar un `CASE` ya que de esta forma podemos establecer un orden de preferencia en los filtros:

```
SELECT * 
       from cli_propiedades 
       WHERE status<66 
             AND estado=1 
             AND 1 = (CASE WHEN codigo_propiedad IS NOT NULL AND codigo_propiedad like '<variable>%' THEN 1
                           WHEN localidad IS NOT NULL AND localidad like '%<variable>%' THEN 1
                           WHEN direccion IS NOT NULL AND direccion like'%<variable>%' THEN 1
                           WHEN cp IS NOT NULL AND cp like '%<variable>%' THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                      END)
      ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: La duda seria, si por ejemplo en `codigo_propiedad` conincide con una letra o dos, y en localidad o direccion estan esas misma letras pero en otro resultado (no sé si me doy a enteder), mostraria bien el resultado?

Comment: Si una fila coincide con el patrón del like de `codigo_propiedad`, se mostrará en los resultados, si no coincide, pero si lo hace `localidad` se mostrará también y así con cada uno de los casos.

Comment: Es complejo este caso, de momento si hace bien la busqueda, pero solo si agrego una letra ejemplo la **e** aperece todo lo que se busca anteriormente con esa letra, pero si ya le agrego otra en este caso seria **es** no aparece ningun resultado, sabrias como arreglarlo? y gracias por esta solucion, me has ayudado bastante

Comment: Si tu patrón es `%ES%` en todos los casos, y no encuentras resultados, es por que en ninguna de las columnas ese patrón coincide. preguntas: 1) la consulta que publicaste, es la que estás usando? 2) El filtro de `estado` no influye en los resultados que estas esperando?

Comment: Si busco el patron `%ES%` y si solo de sa el caso en la ultima opcion deberia de aparecer pero no lo hace, respondo a tus preguntas, 1) si y no ahora uso como prueba la opcion que aportaste, 2) el esado es si está desactivado o no (cosas de trabajo) y el BBDD esta todo activado es decir todo en **1**

Comment: @juank, tu comentario me deja perplejo, de hecho, la consulta de Roy también debería funcionar de igual manera a como lo estás planteando. ¿No podría ser un problema de collation? De casualidad ¿no estás buscando por `%ES%` y no matchea una valor como `*Es*`? Otra cosa no se me ocurre, aquí es donde se justifica que armes un [mcve].

Comment: es que es complejo y no entiendo lo que pasa, da gual si se busca con mayusculu- minuscula, si se pasa de un caracter no funciona, puede ser error mio probablemente y no lo estoy viendo, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Tal vez se trate de un error de interpretación nuestra. Revisa este fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4db64/1/1 es un modelo mas pequeño, con solo dos columnas pero que grafica de alguna manera el comportamiento esperable de la solución de Roy y la mía. Confirmemos que efectivamente sea eso lo que esperas. Por otro lado, te sugiero que pruebes el LIKE de forma individual y que el `%ES%` funcione en cada una de las columnas por separado.